# A + B задачка на python

Tags: python-3.x

Имеются два файла input.txt и output.txt. В input.txt находятся пары чисел, записанные по строкам. В output.txt нужно записать суммы пар этих чисел построчно.

```
f = open('M:\input.txt', 'r')
n = open('M:\output.txt', 'w')

data = []
q = 0

x = f.read()
x.split()
data.append(x)
for data in range(len(data)):
    c = data[q] + data[q+1]
    data.append(c)
    i += 2
    n.write(str(c))

print(data)

f.close
n.close
```

Я пытался сделать это этим кодом. В строке 'c = data[q] + data[q+1]' появляется ошибка 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable' Не знаю, как исправить. Я новичёк в программировании, так что прошу помощи у более опытных. Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: `data.append` добавляет **один** элемент к списку. Почему бы не воспользоваться отладкой и не наблюдать за содержимым переменных? А вообще логика в программе отсутствует. Стоит расписать шаги на бумаге, потом уже реализовывать

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: with open('input.txt') as f:
   ...:     vals = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()]
   ...:

In [6]: vals
Out[6]: [['1', '5'], ['10', '15'], ['16', '88']]

In [7]: with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
   ...:     for val in vals:
   ...:         f.write(f'{sum(map(int, val))}\n')
```

Результат:

```
6
25
104
```